# Click() on HtmlArea and nothing changes, why?

Tags: htmlunit

I'm trying my hand at HtmlUnity and have ran into trouble when I try to click an area with javaScript.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlArea;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlMap;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class ToPost {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws MalformedURLException 
     * @throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
        HtmlPage page;
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        page = webClient.getPage("http://www.hidrografico.pt/previsao-mares.php");
        System.out.println(page.getTitleText());
        HtmlPage pagePortoLeixoes = setPort(page, "362,64,440,90");
        System.out.println("Are they the same? "+page.asXml().equals(pagePortoLeixoes.asXml()));
    }

    private static HtmlPage setPort(HtmlPage page, String coordinatesPort) throws IOException {
        HtmlMap map = page.getHtmlElementById("FPMap1");
        Iterable<HtmlElement> childAreas = map.getChildElements();
        HtmlArea tempArea;
        for (HtmlElement htmlElement : childAreas) {
            tempArea = (HtmlArea) htmlElement;
            if(tempArea.getCoordsAttribute().equals(coordinatesPort)){
                System.out.println("Found Leixoes! --> "+ tempArea.asXml());
                return tempArea.click();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I don't show it here but I double-check in my full code that I'm really not in the page I want.

What is happening? Why doesn't the click work?

Answer (score 0):

HtmlUnit .click() often works poorly when "complex" javascript is involved.

> http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlElement.html#click()
>
> Simulates clicking on this element, returning the page in the window that has the focus after the element has been clicked. Note that the returned page may or may not be the same as the original page, depending on the type of element being clicked, the presence of JavaScript action listeners, etc

In this case, you'll have to find another way to catch the data.

What i did see is that using .rss links, it gives you direct links to cities ...
eg : http://www.hidrografico.pt/previsao-mares-aveiro.php

Another way would have been to forge a POST request (check for exemple with Httpfox which requests are done when you're stuck getting a page)